# how to access class instance variables VS class methods

Tags: ruby

I recently ran into a conceptual ruby issue with accessing class instance variables via the class instead of the matching class method.  for example...

```
class Test
  @foo = nil
  def self.foo foo
    @foo = foo
  end
end
```

How can i access `@foo` from `Test` without renaming `self.foo`?  There are obviously simple ways around this, but this is more of a functional Ruby question than an actual issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Module#class_eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) or [`Object#instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get).

```
class Test
  @foo = nil
  def self.foo foo
    @foo = foo
  end
end

Test.foo(12)
Test.class_eval('@foo') # => 12
Test.instance_variable_get('@foo') # => 12
```

Comment: @brewster, if you don't already know, think about why `class_eval` and `instance_eval` both work in this situation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yeah it makes total sense, its just interesting how many possible options there are (with no seemingly best practice option over the others) to choose from.

Comment: brewster, I agree, but here my vote would be for `instance_variable_get`, because it reads best.

Answer (score 0):

I'd name the setter more explicitly and provide an explicit class getter...

```
@foo = nil

def self.foo=(foo)
    @foo = foo
end

def self.foo
  @foo
end
```

Comment: yeah i know there are simpler ways around it... it came up because the  DSL requirements want the setter without a `=`.  But it just raised an internal ruby question i was curious about.